# How does one read words with a "yud" in Targum?

Tags: pronunciation, aramaic, targumin

While doing "Shenayim Mikrah" I encounter many words that have a "yud" as second to last letter. For example the word "cities" is "קִרְוָיךְ". Is the yud pronounced during reading? I.e. is this read as "kirvach" or as "kirvaych"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

As I learned in the various Aramaic language classes I took in Revel, the yud in these cases is silent, and only exists to show the plurality.

The parallel is to Hebrew, where the yud appears after the segol, but is also entirely unpronounced. For example in אֲבוֹתֶיךָ, it is to be pronounced avotecha, not avoteycha.