# How Do Yemenites Read Yissachar?

Tags: minhag, pronunciation, yemenite-temani

I was reading Torah recently and someone came up and asked me how I pronounced Yissachar. I didn't realize there were multiple ways of reading the name. He told me there was a dispute and so he wanted to know how my tradition pronounced it. I told him I never received any specifics about it.

I then googled and found this article: http://hirhurim.blogspot.co.il/2008/05/yisachar-or-yisaschar.html

however this article seems to be traditional rather than tradition based. And by that I mean that it seems like scholars are reading back into a discrepancy rather than having a solid tradition passed down. Since I know Yemenites did an excellent job passing down tradition, I want to know if they also have multiple ways of pronouncing the name during a Torah reading.

Comment: IIRC the disputes about this word date back to Ben Asher and Ben Naftali. As you expected, all the modern "traditions" that aren't just "Yissakhar" are questionable late variants which should probably be forgotten about, though just relying on the Yemenite way (whatever it may be) is quite a bit shortsighted. Yemenites for instance don't have Ta'am Tachton despite that being the Ma'aravai tradition.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4290/759

Comment: For the record, neither in the Aleppo, nor in the Leningrad codex are there any dots on the second ש, which implies that it shouldn't be pronounced (OK, there's a mysterious one at Chronicles I. 6:57). The better question is whether it is with a dagesh or not.

Comment: would this not be similar to yavorakhkho unlike how i hear ashkanazim pronounce yovarakhakho. teimonim say yissokhor not yisoskhor

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov So is the second ש pronounced, and if so, how? as a sh, a s, or some variant?

Comment: @mevaqesh there is a dagesh in the first s and the second s is silent. yiss(s)okhor

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov Nice clarification. Consider posting an answer.

Comment: you can also ask about the silent yodh in the word einakho. its not einaikho like arabic einaik, your eyes

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov do you agree with the existing answer to this question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44776/11532?  I have no idea if Aramaic is more similar to Hebrew or Arabic.  (If not, maybe add your own.)

Comment: @heshy i agree with the answer. how the word was pronounced historically is a different matter which i dont recall learning

Comment: It would appear Masoretes agreed on pronunciation. They differed on the qere vocalization: BA preferred יִשָּׂשכָר, BN יִשְׁשָׂכָר and a third named משה מוחה spelled it as יִשְׂשָׂכָר.

Comment: As far as this question is concerned: https://youtu.be/bkRko6wyAwU?t=2327

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pFhwevOfnY) of Yemenite Torah reading (at 1:45), the Yemenite pronunciation is Yisachar, omitting the second ש, as is the prevalent practice in other communities.